# Array filter method does not wok

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use the filter method to remove an item from an array based on an index but it is not working. eg: below `filteredGroceries` should return `[{"name":"Apples","completed":false},{"name":"231312"},{"name":"765656"}]`.  But it returns all the elements in groceries.
 I am sure I am making a newbie mistake.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var groceries= [{"name":"Apples","completed":false},{"name":"231312"},{"name":"454334"},{"name":"765656"}];
var indexToRemove=2;
var filteredGroceries = groceries.filter(item => item.index !== indexToRemove);
```

Comment: None of your `items` has an `.index` property.

Comment: You probably mean `groceries.filter((item, index) => index !== indexToRemove)`. But why not just use `slice` and `splice`?

Comment: Did you mean to use a [second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in your callback?

Comment: @xufox: thank you. As you can understand, I am trying to get my feet wet in Javascript. I am not using splice, as that method mutates the Array (I am using ReactJs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define the `index` argument.

```js
var groceries= [{"name":"Apples","completed":false},{"name":"231312"},{"name":"454334"},{"name":"765656"}];
var indexToRemove=2;
var filteredGroceries = groceries.filter((item, index) => index !== indexToRemove);

console.log(filteredGroceries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a function with one argument to filter whereas if you passed two, the second is the index:

```
var filteredGroceries = groceries.filter((item,index) => index !== indexToRemove);
```

As it stands, you are accessing the `'index'` attribute of each object in the array which is always `undefined` so all elements pass the test.

The documentation for `.filter` shows that to get the index, you need the second argument:

> ```
> var newArray = arr.filter(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your callback returns an option item, it does not have a property index
Add another params

```
var groceries= [{"name":"Apples","completed":false},{"name":"231312"},{"name":"454334"},{"name":"765656"}];
var indexToRemove=2;
var filteredGroceries = groceries.filter((item, index) => index !== indexToRemove);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var filteredGroceries = groceries.filter((item, i) => i !== indexToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredGroceries = groceries.filter(item => item.index !== indexToRemove);
```

This line is making new array out of existing one and it is not returning element/object that has index key in it. Considering that your array of objects contains non of the objects with key index, you get whole array back. If you would like to eliminate second element from the array, you should use groceries.splice(1, 0)